# Flutter - Location package showing address in Emulator but not in real device

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, fluttermap

Here's is the package I've used: [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location)

**My provider class**

```
class LocationProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  LocationData? _currentPosition;
  Location? location = Location();
  List<geo.Placemark>? placemarks;

  String? street;
  String? locality;
  String? country;

  getLocation() async {
    print('getLocation() was called');
    _currentPosition = await location!.getLocation();

    print('Current Position: $_currentPosition');

    placemarks = await geo.placemarkFromCoordinates(
      _currentPosition!.latitude!,
      _currentPosition!.longitude!,
    );

    print('Placemarks: $placemarks');

    street = placemarks?[0].street;
    locality = placemarks?[0].locality;
    country = placemarks?[0].country;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is working accurately on Emulator. But in real device it shows null in places where I've used these variables.

In my console, I see only `getLocation() was called` but other data are not printed inside my console.

This is how it's called inside the build() of the required widget

```
final locationDetail = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false);
```

I've added the following permissions inside android>app>src>main>AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

The above codes are working in Emulator but not in real device.

Comment: could you confirm the API level of the device?

Comment: API level of my device is 30.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following lines of code in the provider class. Earlier it was in some other file.

```
_serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
if (!_serviceEnabled) {
  _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
  if (!_serviceEnabled) {
    return;
  }
}

_permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
  _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    return;
  }
}
```

The above lines were added before

```
_currentPosition = await location!.getLocation();
```